# Laravel Blade: pass array as parameter to yield section

Tags: arrays, laravel, parameters, laravel-blade, yield

i would like to pass an array as parameter from my controller to the blade template.

My controller looks like this:

```
$myArray = array('data' => 'data');
return View::make('myTableIndex')
    ->nest('myTable', 'my_table_template', $myArray)
```

In my blade template i've got a yield like this:

```
@yield('myTable', $myArray)
```

But i've get the error:

```
Error: Array to string conversion
```

That's because the yield function only accepts strings, right?

Background is:
I want a table template which i can use dynamically for multiple purpose or multiple data, so i can use the same template for multiple tables and just pass the columns and content as array.

How can i pass an array to my yield section?

Comment: Why not use a `section` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's it use a `section` in a separate file and `include` it.

Comment: But with include i just can use 1 variable. The one i give in the controller. So it's not dynamic anymore because in my included template i have to use the specific variable.

Comment: You can pass a name for your variable: `@include('viewname', 'variablename')` so you can use variable name like `$variablename` in your included `view`.

Comment: Interesting. But where is my variable(array) than? @include('viewname', 'variablename', $array) doesn't work.

Comment: It should be `@include('view.name', ['varname' => $array])`.

Comment: It works!! Thanks alot, very nice. Thank you :) Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: WC, Probably I should answer it for future vieewers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use a separate file and include the file using `@include` while you may pass the data with a dynamic variable name so you'll be able to use that variable name in your included view, for example:

```
@include('view.name', ['variableName' => $array])
```

So, in the `view.name` view you can use/access the `$array` using `$variableName` variable and you are free to use any name for `variableName`.

So, in the separate view i.e: `view.name`, you may use a `section` and do whatever you want to do with `$variableName`.

---

*Note: The problem was solved in the comment section but added as an answer here for the future reference so any viewer come here for similar problem will get the answer easily.*

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

`@yield` produce a section, like an include but with the included template defined from the children

`@yield` does not accept parameters, and it makes sense since the parent does not have to knows what children will implement.

If you want to pass parameters to the template, an `@include` probably suits better the case

```
@include('subview', ['parameter_name' => 'parameter_value'])
```

Otherwise a simple php variable declared by the parent and used by the children can work with a `@yield` (and also with `@include`)

```
@php
$my_var='my_value'
@endphp
@yield('my_section')
```

If you want to send data from children to the parent, you can do it at the parent declaration, where you add it:

```
@extends('parent_view',['parameter_name'=>'parameter_value'])
```